# How can I make php and py in a certain directory display as text or download?

Tags: php, python, .htaccess

How can I make php and py in a certain directory display as text?

I am working on a file hosting program, but I need to make php files either download, or display as text.

I haven't been able to find any information on this.

Comment: [SimpleHTTPServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html)

Comment: How does this relate to my question? Sorry im a bit confused.

Comment: How is this a PHP or Python question ? How is this a programming question at all actually ? It's all about your HTTP server configuration... You want to post this on a sysadmin site like serverfault.

Comment: The question is related. The answer to my question will help develop a php supported file hosting system.

Comment: @user9148619 this is __still__ unrelated (and OT here).  Your question is not about programming, it's about system configuration, and the fact that you need this system configuration for a program you're writing doesn't change anything to it.

Answer (score 1):

It depend on HTTP server software that you used (nginx, apache, etc)

example for nginx config, just remove block that handle php interpreter:

```
# remove this lines until end block
--> location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
--> ... Other code
--> }
```

All php files will displayed as text, if you still need to execute php file on index.php, then you need edit it instead of delete all block, like this:

```
location = /index.php {
... Other code
}
```

example for apache server, put on .htaccess file on directory (refer from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4237000/6682759)):

```
php_flag engine off 
#This will prevent apache from executing *.php-files

AddType text/plain php
#this wil display php-files in browser (if not, browser will want to download file!)
```

Comment: "Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault."

Comment: The question is related. The answer to my question will help develop a php supported file hosting system.

Comment: When I run that, I get error 500. When I remove `php_flag engine off`, It gives error 403. when I remove `AddType text/plain php`, I get error 500.

Comment: try just put `php_flag engine off`

Comment: I have. Error 500.

Comment: I repeat : __"Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault."__ - and there's obviously __nothing__ "directly involving programming or programming tools" here. It's 101% sysadmin stuff.