# How to show uploaded php file as plain text instead of executing it in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload

Edit a `testme.php` file in /tmp.

```
<?php
echo  "test";
?>
```

Edit a new post titled `test` and  upload file `/tmp/testme.php` ,pubish it with url `http://home.local/wp/?p=4785`.
[image]

I want to see the content in testme,click it,pop up new window in wordpress.
[image]

Go on to click it.`test` shown in webpage.

My expect :
1.just click `testme` in test post for one time.
2.show the `testme.php`  as plain text  ,

```
<?php
echo  "test";
?>
```

instead of the result of executing `testme.php`.

```
test
```

I make a configuration according some material `show php file as plain text in apache`.

sudo vim  /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.home.local
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        <Directory /var/www/html>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            allow from all
            php_flag engine off
            AddType text/plain php
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Reboot apache2(build in debian).

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

To open the post `http://home.local/wp/?p=4785`,i got the following output in webpage:

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

Comment: Maybe you can show it as text, like this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236951/how-to-show-php-files-as-plain-text-in-apache

Comment: If possible then please provide some detail explanation about your requirement.

Comment: I just inform you there is a so many plugins are available in WordPress as per match your requirement.
Use this search term "wordpress open popup on click"

wordpress.org/plugins/

Comment: Your question is not clear, please edit your question to make it understandable

Comment: Why can't you add the PHP codes in a plain text file and show the contents (just the extension alone differs)?

Comment: If you really must, changing the directory to `/var/www/html/wp-content/uploads` as in `<Directory /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads>` should work, assuming WordPress is installed in the directory `/var/www/html` and that PHP files are uploaded to the default `uploads` folder. You could also create a `.htaccess` file in that `uploads` folder, and enter `AddType text/plain php` in that `.htaccess` file. But either way, PHP files in the `uploads` folder would be treated as plain-text files. (The PHP code would never be executed)

Comment: @Sally CJ,well done as your suggestion,please post it as answer,i give you the 50 grade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have the right code — `AddType text/plain php`, which will make Apache treats PHP files (or files where the name ends with `.php`) as plain-text files.

But assuming the following:

- You have WordPress installed in the `/var/www/html` directory.
- The PHP files are uploaded to the default `uploads` folder in WordPress (`wp-content/uploads`).

If you set the directory to `/var/www/html/wp-content/uploads` as in:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads>
  AddType text/plain php
</Directory>
```

You'd get the results you wanted — only PHP files in the `uploads` folder will be treated as plain-text files, and *not* all PHP files in the `/var/www/html` directory. This explains the issue with "*To open the post `http://home.local/wp/?p=4785`, I got the following output*", where that output is the code in the file `/var/www/html/index.php`. I mean, you used `<Directory /var/www/html>`, which makes Apache treats the `index.php` file as a plain-text file, instead of executing the PHP code in the file.

**ALTERNATE METHOD: Use the `.htaccess` file.**

Particularly if you can't edit or have no access to the Apache's configuration (`.conf`) file.

1. Create `.htaccess` in the `uploads` folder, if it's not already there.
2. Then add `AddType text/plain php` in that file.

### Additional Notes

> I want to see the content in `testme.php`, click it, pop up new window

I'm sure you can do that or already have the code/solution, but an easy way, is just add `target="_blank"` to the attachment/file link.. or with JavaScript, you can use [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open).

And you must take full *security* measures since allowing people to upload PHP files could harm your site and/or your site users.

Comment: It is build on  127.0.0.1  as my personal notebook,no people can upload php files .

Comment: Ok, but still, it's a good thing to keep in mind by all of us; not just you — WordPress restricts uploading PHP files for a good reason, you know. Thanks for accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to accomplish? It seems you're trying to get a hyperlink that displays the contents of a PHP file. WordPress posts are stored in the database. So when you say "publish it", what are you talking about? The database entry that refers to a WordPress post, or the PHP file? If all you want on the screen is the unexecuted contents of the PHP file, you shouldn't be publishing a WordPress "post". What is contained in the post? If you're talking about putting a PHP file as the CONTENT of a post, that would be a different thing too. Probably the easiest way to display the content of a PHP file is to just rename it to a text file.

**myFile.php => myFile.php.txt**