# finfo returns wrong MIME type on some JS files (text/x-c++)?

Tags: mime-types, php-5.3, fileinfo

I have php 5.3 and use finfo to determine the MIME type of uploaded files.
For some javascript files however, I get mime type text/x-c++, which is of course incorrect.

Does anyone have an idea why this happens sometimes. Because of this, I cannot allow uploads of JS-files in a way based on checking the mime type.

The contents of a file that returns this mime type is:

```
(function($) {

$(document).ready(function() {


        $(function() {
        // OPACITY OF BUTTON SET TO 50%
        $(".fade").css("opacity","1.0");

        // ON MOUSE OVER
        $(".fade").hover(function () {

        // SET OPACITY TO 100%
        $(this).stop().animate({
        opacity: 0.7
        }, "quick");
        },

        // ON MOUSE OUT
        function () {

        // SET OPACITY BACK TO 50%
        $(this).stop().animate({
        opacity: 1.0
        }, "quick");
        });
    });


// End of closure & jquery wraping
});
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same issue the other day (with PDF files being uploaded as application/data), as far as I know this is a browser issue and not a server side one, as I had two browsers upload the exact same PDF, one said application/PDF and the other application/data, my only suggestion to you use since checking the content type is somewhat flaky, you should do your own type checking.

For your case, I would just ensure that the mime type starts with "text/", and check the file extension of the uploaded file.  If you're particularlly brave you may write some code that does a syntax check of the uploaded file, but that's probably going to be a lot more work than you want to do.

Comment: the problem when allowing "text/", is that we would be allowing PHP and other dangerous scripts to be uploaded, hidden inside a.js file or something else and that's something we'd like to avoid. Do you know if this is a problem with the FINFO functions?

Comment: I would recommend this for your upload directory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271899/disable-php-in-directory-including-all-sub-directories-with-htaccess