# Disable a file execution inside a folder .htaccess rule

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a site where I want to disable certain extensions of file execution just for that folder.

EG: www.yoursite.com/cache/test.php

should not be executed.

I tried this code :

```
<FilesMatch "\.(htaccess|htpasswd|ini|phps|fla|psd|log|sh|zip|exe|pl|jsp|asp|htm|sh|cgi|py|php)$">
  Order Allow,Deny
  Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

But this stopped my sites functionality.

I just want this rule to be applied inside cache folder but I can not place the `.htaccess` file inside because this folder is regularly cleared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do is place that `.htaccess` file within that specific cache folder.

> `.htaccess` files provide a way to make configuration changes on a **per-directory basis**.

[Apache HTTP Server Tutorial: .htaccess files](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html)

Placing that rule in your `.htaccess` file in the root of your website will enable those rules on your entire site.

---

If you want this rule to be enabled from outside that cache folder, you might want to try this rule in your main `.htaccess` file -

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^cache/.*\.(htaccess|htpasswd|ini|...)$ /access_denied.php
```

The rule tests to see if the requested file's

- URL starts with `cache/`
- contains any of the file extensions listed (separated with a pipe character)

If those conditions are all met, it passes that call to the `access_denied.php` script where you could display an appropriate error message.

Comment: but when I clean the cache folder that file also gets deleted

is there any other rule which can disable this execution

Answer (score 4):

Try adding this line to you root .htaccess file :

```
RewriteRule ^cache/.*\.(htaccess|htpasswd|ini|phps?|fla|psd|log|sh|zip|exe|pl|jsp|asp|htm|sh|cgi|py)$ - [F]
```

The flag will result in displaying a 403 Forbidden Error

Comment: This one works pervectly. But make sure you placed it before RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d and RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f or existing files will still be executed