# How can I prevent php execution in parts of a website?

Tags: php, security, execution, suphp

I have a LAMP server running php as suphp, with several websites. If I'm not mistaken, php code can normally be prevented from running in a certain part of a website by putting "php_flag engine off" in a .htaccess file located in the corresponding directory, alternatively put "php_flag engine off" in the VirtualHost directive in Apache. But this apparantly is only valid for regular mod_php and not suphp. So how can I achieve the same thing in suphp?

For example, I want to disable PHP code inside the www.foo.com/images/ but allow it anywhere else on that site.

I have searched here on stackoverflow but only found solutions for mod_php.

Comment: This is more a question for http://stackoverflow.com/ and should be migrated there ...

Comment: [Same question with good answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271899/disable-php-in-directory-including-all-sub-directories-with-htaccess)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following into .htaccess

```
RemoveHandler .php
RemoveType .php
```

in the folder which you need to disable PHP for

Comment: that quick solution did the job. wonderful! thanks :-)

Comment: Also, depending on your server config, beware of extensions like `.php3`, `.php4`, `.php5`...

Comment: @DoubleGras  yes of course, I forgot about them. Thanks!