# Prevent PHP parsing in a particular folder

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to prevent a particular folder to parse PHP files. 
I have used the following code in .htaccess

```
php_flag engine off
```

It is giving me '**Internal Server Error**'

Then I tried this:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
   php_flag engine off
</IfModule>
```

But, the second one doesn't seems working. How can i prevent the particular folder other than this?

Comment: To prevent it to not parse, you are saying that you want it to parse, so just leave it as it is and it will parse as normal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271899/disable-php-in-directory-including-all-sub-directories-with-htaccess

Answer (score 1):

Both are exactly the same. `<IfModule>` got nothing with PHP. Please [check Apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#ifmodule). And you got `500` from your httpd, because you got `AllowOverride None` set in httpd's config, so all `php_flag` will cause this error. You need to enable it, by setting it to (at least) `AllowOverrides Options`, and restarting your httpd.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using mod_php, you could put (either in a .htaccess in /USERS or in your httpd.conf for the USERS directory)

```
RemoveHandler .php
```

or

```
RemoveType .php
```

(depending on whether PHP is enabled using AddHandler or AddType)