# Apache: Disable php in a directory

Tags: php, apache

I want to disable php in a directory on my server.
I thought that setting Options -ExecCGI in httpd.conf would prevent php scripts from being executed, but obviously I am wrong.

So, this is what I have in my httpd.conf, which obviously does not work:

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/(path_to_directory)/dirname">
    Options -ExecCGI
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

The question is, how can I prevent php scripts from being executed in a specific folder?
Can in be done in httpd.conf or do I have to use a .htaccess file?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Apache administration and as such better fits to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable PHP in directory (including all sub-directories) with .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271899/disable-php-in-directory-including-all-sub-directories-with-htaccess)

Answer (score 13):

`php_flag engine off`only works if you are using `mod_php`(as well as `mod_php7.x`) than `php-fpm`

Seems you are using `php-fpm`, so add the further lines into `httpd.conf`:

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/(path_to_directory)/dirname">
<FilesMatch ".+\.*$">
SetHandler !
</FilesMatch>
</Directory>
```

or these in `.htaccess` in the Directory you don't expect the execution of PHP:

```
<FilesMatch ".+\.*$">
SetHandler !
</FilesMatch>
```

---

I have tested it on an Unix Platform rather than a Windows, Hope it would help U.

Comment: Other solutions did not work for me probably due to server configuration. `Sethandler !` Did the work for me!

Comment: SetHandler worked for me as well, thank you!  Although you can simplify your answer by changing from a FilesMatch block to just `<Files "*.*">` which should give the same effect with less regex. :)

Comment: Is there something wrong with the regex? `.+\.*$` matches files ending with dot characters?

Answer (score 9):

you can do this with .htaccess file. you need to place a .htaccess file in the folder you don't want to execute the php with following htaccess code.

```
<Files *.php>
deny from all
</Files>
```

see here in more details http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-disable-php-execution-in-certain-wordpress-directories/

Also you can Try to disable the [engine option](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/apache.configuration.php#ini.engine) in your .htaccess file:

```
php_flag engine off
```

Comment: .htaccess parent not affected on child .htaccess .

Comment: For Apache 2.4 use `Require all denied` instead of `deny from all`

Comment: With PHP FPM, you can't use `php_admin_flag` or any similar ilk in your apache configs any more.  On high performance sites, htaccess processing also slows your site down just a touch with extra disk I/O looking at every single directory for .htaccess files.  So if you can avoid using them, do so.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `php.ini` in the root folder of `xampp` inside PHP and set engine to off:

```
engine=off
```