# How to set php_flag per-directory using php-fpm?

Tags: php, php-ini

## My problem

I want to turn off the *php engine* in a specific folder, where users can upload files, but I can't seem to figure it out.

**PHP Version:** 5.5.26

**PHP mode:** php-fpm (FastCGI Process Manager)

**Apache version:** 2.2.29

(**Server:** Synology DS212j - DSM 5.2)

*Anything else you need to know?*

## What I've tried so far:

#### Disable from .htaccess-file

This is not supported by php-fpm (and some other modes), it gives a 500 error, logging:

```
Invalid command 'php_value', perhaps mis-spelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration.
```

#### Per-directory php.ini

I've tried per-directory php.ini-files (putting an additional php.ini-file in the avatars directory), but didn't get that working. PHP never loaded the file. Not sure what I did wrong, I tried naming it both *php.ini* and *.user.ini*, neither worked.

#### Main php.ini section

I also tried using a section in the main *php.ini* file,

```
[path=/path/to/secure/dir]
engine = off
max_execution_time = 300
```

When I did that and ran `phpinfo()` in a file in the secure dir the `max_execution_time` was set to 300 (so the file has been reloaded), but the engine was still running (I assume, since the `phpinfo()` was shown).

#### php-fpm pools

I've also read about php-fpm pools, but it seems to me that you can only specify pools by domain/vhost, ***am I wrong?***

#### Edit vhost

I tried disabling it from the vhosts-file (is that what it's called?), in a `<Directory /path/to/secure/dir>` section as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18948152/739534), but that wasn't supported either.

### Extra info

I'm building an application based on [Paniques's HUGE](https://github.com/panique/huge). In [the .htaccess-file](https://github.com/panique/huge/blob/master/public/avatars/.htaccess) in the upload directory the php engine is turned off (for security reasons), using `php_flag engine off`.

Answer (score 4):

Try this .htaccess file:

```
<Files "*.php">
  SetHandler none
  SetHandler default-handler
  Options -ExecCGI
  RemoveHandler .php
</Files>
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_flag engine off
</IfModule>
```

Should work both with php-fpm and mod_php.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do something like this inside any of your httpd.conf files:

```
<Directory "/path/to/secure/dir">
<Files "*.*">
SetHandler !
</Files>
</Directory>
```

HTT Hardrain, I got this technique from his answer here: [Apache: Disable php in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27776350/apache-disable-php-in-a-directory)

Comment: For anyone wondering, the reason for the <Files> block is because the Apache manual notes using SetHandler None might break things like Options Indexes.