# XAMPP: How to include <a href="sample.php"> without running php file when it is clicked

Tags: php, html

I currently have some code in my HTML page such as:

```
<a href="examplecode/sample.php">Click here to view this PHP code sample.</p>
```

The problem is that my web page is also written in PHP, so when the file is clicked the PHP code runs, which is not what I want: I want the code to be simply displayed in the web browser, and I want it to be possible to download the file. How should I proceed? I would prefer a solution where I do not have to change the `.php` file extension. Thanks.

NOTE: I've tried the solution outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271899/disable-php-in-directory-including-all-sub-directories-with-htaccess). I've included the following line:

```
php_flag engine off
```

in my `.htaccess` file. However, if I place the `.htaccess` file in the `examplecode` directory, the PHP code runs, and if I place it in the directory above where `index.php` is found, then none of the PHP files in that root directory run. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable PHP in directory (including all sub-directories) with .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271899/disable-php-in-directory-including-all-sub-directories-with-htaccess)

Comment: I believe that so long as you don't have the <?php...?> tags, the code will just print out as text even without modifying .htaccess and without changing file extension. That's how it works on my Apache2 server, anyhow.

Comment: Yes, that's true, but I need to keep the <?php ... ?> because I want the file to be a working file. I've tried the solution in the related post, but my PHP file still runs, and I don't want it to. I won't be able to change the server configuration once I upload my page, so I need a solution based on an .htaccess file in the directory where the source code is located. Can you please make a suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You could write another script called, for instance, `show.php` that can be called like `examplecode/show.php?script=sample.php` which contains something like the following:

```
<?php

$file = $_GET['file'];
if (file_exists('/path/to/webapp/examplecode/' . $file) && 'show.php' !== $file && strlen($file) - strlen('.php') == strrpos($file, '.php')) {
    echo '<code>' . file_get_contents('/path/to/webapp/examplecode/' . $file) . '</code>';
    exit;
}

echo 'Script not found: ' . $file;
```

Such a script might be usefule for your purpose if you want to execute the file at some point anyway without using things like `eval()`.

**Be careful, though, as you need good validation of the filename entered and you should not include any sensitive data, like database passwords etc. in those files!**

Comment: Sure, but this solution embeds the code in the page. I want the code to open up in a separate window all of its own. Is this possible?

Comment: If you want the plain file to open in a new browser window, without including/embedding/whatever, you would have to adjust your .htaccess file, see comment of @Machavity on your question for this kind of behaviour :)

Comment: Please see my updated post. No matter where I place the php_flag directive, things are not running.