# securities with upload image php

Tags: php, image, file-upload

I have a upload image function on my web app, I tried to upload a `php` file with a code like this `<script>alert('XSS')</script>` the file is `hack.php.jpg` then, I upload it and it is uploaded, my fear of this is that, will the `script` will run and return something to the malicious user or it will ignore the `script` inside of the `.jpg` ? Here are the list of function of my upload image:

1) It will rename the image then will be saved on the folder.
2) only accepted `extensions` are `jpg, png, jpeg` .
3) file size `< 1000000`.
4) `uniqid()` used for renaming the name of the `img`.
5) I use `unlink()` and `move_upload_file()` for saving the `img` and deleting the `img` on the folder.
6) my `<form> enctype` is `multipart/form-data` and `accept="image/*"`.

I learned my code in `codecourse php upload file` video.

Answer (score 0):

How do you parse the extension of the file?
Ideally, you completely rename the file. For example to "randomhash.jpeg/jpg/png". That way it is impossible for it to ever contain the ".php" extension.

Another thing you can do is disable PHP code execution (in nginx or Apache) in the folder where you store your images.

You can also additionally make use of the functions [getimagesize](http://php.net/getimagesize) and [exif_imagetype](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php) to check for it being a valid image. Just keep in mind that those functions are not foolproof.

Comment: thank you, any recommended tutorials for disabling php code execution (APACHE) ?

Comment: @phew Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/1272068/6275228 or http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/74668/apache-disable-php-in-a-directory.

Comment: i have additonal question, my photos is too big, `1MB` atleast, I want below 500 or 400 KB only. Because the loading is too slow