# How to use mkdir function to create folder and set it can't run php file?

Tags: php, html

How to use mkdir to create folder, and set it can't run php file? thx
I would like to create a file upload system and want to prevent user whose upload the hacking php file to hack my website, so I hope the folder can't run php file.

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_FILES['files'])){
$errors= array();
foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
    $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
    $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];  
       if(empty($errors)==true){
        if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
            mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);        
        }
        if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"$desired_dir/".$file_name);
        }else{                                  
            $new_dir="$desired_dir/".$file_name.time();
             rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;               
        }
}
if(empty($error)){
    echo "Success";
}
}?>
```

Comment: Just create a .htaccess file that contain: "php_flag engine off" in the folder.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1272068/6030450

Comment: it work!!!!! thank you very much